# Pipe output of command into Windows Notepad (Cygwin)

Tags: cygwin, pipe, stdin

Using Cygwin, I'd like to open the output of a command in Notepad (notepad2-mod, actually). E.g. in a pure UNIX environment I can do `grep ^flags /proc/cpuinfo | vi -`.
Notepad doesn't offer an option to read from stdin.
What is the most elegant way to do it, preferrably without using a temporary file?

Answer (score 0):

echo "foo" > notepad.txt

your command  > textfile.txt

Comment: I'm specifically asking about how to do it using a pipe (avoiding creating a temp file)